# SSRS and subscriptions in SQL jobs

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, jobs

I have create a subscription to a new SSRS Report and I have notice when doing so, there is a new job creates with a GUID. Since this report need to be produce to multiple users with different set of parameters, I create a stored procedure to manage all this.

My question is to know if it is possible to change/modify the job with the GUID that was created thru the report subscription or do I have to create a new job to call my stored procedure?

By creating a separate job to exec my stored procedure, will it duplicate the production of the report ?

Can this GUID job be disable and just run the new job instead ?

I need to understand this before making any change to the original GUID job

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't touch the jobs created by SSRS.

But you can create multiple subscriptions for the same report, with different parameters.

Or if you have a lot of users that need to receive the report, you can create a data-driven subscription.  You need an enterprise edition for this though.